# Alphabetical scroll bar display incorrect data

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I was expecting a list of initials of my items to appear on the right hand side of the screen but for some reason a number is shown instead. Does anyone know what went wrong and how to fix this?

```
enum class Items(@StringRes val nameId: Int, val typeId: Int) {
    Item1(R.string.apple, R.string.fruit),
    Item2(R.string.banana, R.string.fruit),
    Item3(R.string.cherry, R.string.fruit),
    Item4(R.string.date, R.string.fruit),
    Item5(R.string.eggplant, R.string.vegetable),
    Item6(R.string.fig, R.string.fruit),
    Item7(R.string.guava, R.string.fruit),
    Item8(R.string.jackfruit, R.string.fruit),
    Item9(R.string.kiwi, R.string.fruit),
    Item10(R.string.leek, R.string.vegetable),
    Item11(R.string.okra, R.string.vegetable),
    Item12(R.string.pumpkin, R.string.fruit),
    Item13(R.string.rhubarb, R.string.fruit),
    Item14(R.string.spinach, R.string.vegetable),
    Item15(R.string.turnip, R.string.vegetable),
    Item16(R.string.watermelon, R.string.fruit);
}

val items = remember { arrayOf(
        Items.Item1,
        Items.Item2,
        Items.Item3,
        Items.Item4,
        Items.Item5,
        Items.Item6,
        Items.Item7,
        Items.Item8,
        Items.Item9,
        Items.Item10,
        Items.Item11,
        Items.Item12,
        Items.Item13,
        Items.Item14,
        Items.Item15,
        Items.Item16).sortedBy { it.nameId } }
val headers = remember { items.map { it.nameId.first().uppercase() }.toSet().toList() }
Row {
    val listState = rememberLazyListState()
    LazyColumn(
        state = listState,
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
    ) {
        items(items) {
            Column() {
                Text(
                    text = stringResource(id = it.nameId)
                )
                Text(
                    text = stringResource(id = it.typeId)
                )
            }
        }
    }
    val offsets = remember { mutableStateMapOf<Int, Float>() }
    var selectedHeaderIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    fun updateSelectedIndexIfNeeded(offset: Float) {
        val index = offsets
            .mapValues { abs(it.value - offset) }
            .entries
            .minByOrNull { it.value }
            ?.key ?: return
        if (selectedHeaderIndex == index) return
        selectedHeaderIndex = index
        val selectedItemIndex = items.indexOfFirst { it.nameId.first().uppercase() == headers[selectedHeaderIndex] }
        scope.launch {
            listState.scrollToItem(selectedItemIndex)
        }
    }

    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .background(Color.Green)
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectTapGestures {
                    updateSelectedIndexIfNeeded(it.y)
                }
            }
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectVerticalDragGestures { change, _ ->
                    updateSelectedIndexIfNeeded(change.position.y)
                }
            }
    ) {
        headers.forEachIndexed { i, header ->
            Text(
                header,
                modifier = Modifier.onGloballyPositioned {
                    offsets[i] = it.boundsInParent().center.y
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are several places where you are using the resource id (`nameId`) like a string, but it is an integer that refers to the string resource. To use it as a string you need to use something like `stringResource` or `getString`.

**First Location** - Constructing headers

```kotlin
val headers = remember { 
  items.map { 
    it.nameId.first().uppercase() 
  }.toSet().toList() 
}
```

Since `nameId` is a resource ID, it is just an integer. All you are doing here is making a list of the first digit of that integer, which is probably not what you intended. You probably want to convert it to a string first, then get the first digit.

Something like this (or using `getString` instead of `stringResource`)

```kotlin
val headers = remember { 
  items.map { 
    stringResource(it.nameId).first().uppercase() 
  }.toSet().toList() 
}
```

**Second Location** - Sorting the item list

The sorting of your items list probably has a similar issue, and may just be luck that it is in the proper order - since you are sorting by the resource ID and not by the string itself.

```kotlin
sortedBy { it.nameId }
```

instead of

```kotlin
sortedBy { stringResource(it.nameId) }
```

**Third Location** - Matching the selection to the headers list

You'll have to fix this comparison too as well, since again it is pulling the resource ID first digit. Once headers is the actual string, then this will need to use the actual string too.

```kotlin
it.nameId.first().uppercase() == headers[selectedHeaderIndex]
```

Comment: Perfect. Is it possible to show a large initial in the middle of the screen? Every time I tap an initial letter, I cannot see what my finger is tapping?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible although that should probably be a separate question.

Comment: of course, in due course. Thanks for the advice